# How can I use javascript to click these elements?

Tags: javascript

When you sign up to pinterest, it asks you to select 5 topics to build your home feed. I'd like to execute javascript to click 1 of these buttons.

I right clicked on the area I want clicked and clicked "inspect" and I see this code come up:

```html
<div class="interestImage" style="background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/400x/a5/6d/90/a56d900e41ce2a6205fa2d830419e387.jpg)" data-element-type="211" data-aux="{ &quot;interest&quot;: &quot;hairstyles&quot; }"></div>
```

And here is what the page looks like:

[I right clicked on the hairstyles one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT5FR.jpg)

Any idea if I can use javascript for this?

Comment: It's not a captcha, it's just a welcome thing to build your home feed on pinterest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("interestImage")[0].click();
```

This will only work if this element is the first/only element on the page with this class.

Otherwise, you will need to replace the 0 inside the [] with the number that corresponds to the index of that element in the array of elements with that class.  For example, it that's the 3rd element on the page with that class, replace the 0 with a 2.

Comment: actually, it will work as long as there's one or more - it just "clicks" the first such element

Comment: you are correct, document, not Document

Comment: Wait a minute, before we continue any further, I will need to click at least 5 of them. Can I do that? Or is only the first one on the page possible?

Comment: Thanks, borbesaur, I'll give that a try and return here to confirm whether or not it's working for me.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thanks, borbesaur.

Comment: One more thing if you've got time.. Is it possible that I could get the script to pick a random number from say 1 to 10 where it says [0]?

Comment: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) returns a random number between 1 and 10.  
So you can do 
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
document.getElementsByClassName("interestImage")[randomNumber].click();        PS: All I did was google "js random number" to get that Math.random thing.  Please attempt googling whenever possible.  It will help you become a better developer in the long run.